# is there a way for matplotlib to use change the scale of the axis values using the metric system?

Tags: python, matplotlib

One image:

[image]

For example, I'd like to have the second graph display 4k, 2k and the one below 1M, 500K, etc but automatically because scales can vary dramatically.

Is this possible? or is it something I have to implement manually and do text labels?

Comment: To dynamically handle labels and also be able to account for strings in those y-axis labels - you could look at the [auto subplots adjust](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/gallery/pyplots/auto_subplots_adjust.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-auto-subplots-adjust-py) to automatically adjust subplot parameters. Or possibly using `gridspec` [link example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/demo_constrained_layout.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-demo-constrained-layout-py) to modify your y_label values. Not a full answer, but hope it's helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

matplotlib has a [specific formatter `EngFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.EngFormatter) for that very purpose:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, constrained_layout=True)

ax1.set_title('without formatter')
ax1.plot([0,1],[0,1e6])
ax2.set_title('using EngFormatter')
ax2.plot([0,1],[0,1e6])

ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.EngFormatter())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Definitely there is a way, what I did may look a bit unnecessary complicated but it works (I hope)

If it works you need to use "picker" sublibrary of matplotlib applying whole data. The plot I drawn is like;

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tick
import numpy as np

dummy = 2500*np.random.rand(1,20)
dummx = np.linspace(1,20,20)

def myfunc(tick_val, pos):
    if tick_val >= 1000:
        val = int(tick_val) / 1000
        return '{0} k'.format(val)
    else:
        return tick_val
    
plt.plot(dummx,dummy[0])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tick.FuncFormatter(myfunc))
```